# .htaccess redirect root to folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have two independend websites on my server. Of which one website is located in a subfolder of the other. Both websites are accessible over two different domains. Following the folder structure on my server:

```
/www                <- one.com
    /index.html
    /assets
        ...
    /folder         <- two.com
        /.htaccess
        /index.html
        /assets
            ...
```

Therefore, if I want to access website `two` I can do so with the following URLs:

```
one.com/folder
two.com
```

My problem: Using absolute paths to include files (css/js/img) in website `two`, I need to adapt my root depending over which URL the user access website `two`. Following an example for illustration:

---

The html file `/www/folder/index.html` contains an image:

```
<img src="/assets/img.jpg" />
```

If the user access this html file via the domain `one.com/folder/index.html` the image source path gets translated to `one.com/assets/img.jpg` where it won't find any image. Correct would have been `one.com/folder/assets/img.jpg` (one notice the `folder` in the path). Obviously, if the user calls `two.com/index.html` the problem doesn't exist.

---

Therefore, I thought I would change the root (base directory) of website `two` via `.htaccess` mod rewrite depending on which URL gets called. Following the simple pseudo code I would like to implement:

```
if url == one.com/folder*
    root = /folder/
else
    root = /
```

And following what I got so far for my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(www\.)?one\.com
RewriteRule   ^/(.*)$  /folder/$1  [R]
```

Unfortunately, it seems as if I am missing something here. So far it doesn't work. Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place this rule in `/www/.htaccess` folder:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(assets/.+)$ /folder/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Great idea, thank you very much. The only thing is, I forgot to mention the website one hast a similar structure, meaning it contains an `assets` folder as well (updated the question). Therefore it does not work with this solution. Excuse me, I focused to much on the subfolder (`folder`) and did not think anything outside it could actually be important.

Comment: Hmm that changes problem completely. If there is `/assets/` at root then how come `one.com/assets/img.jpg` is causing 404 not found?

Comment: Because I simplified the example: For example website `two` contains a banner (`/assets/banner.jpg`) but website `one` doesn't. Furthermore, website `two` contains js scripts (`/assets/js/script1.js` ...), again website `one` doesn't.
So of course I have the possibility of choosing two different names for the two `assets` folder but isn't this problem solvable with `RewriteCond` and then using your proposed `RewriteRule`? Thank you for your help by the way!

Comment: ok I understand the problem better now. See my updated rule. Now redirect will take place only when a file is not found in `/assets/` folder for website `one`.

Comment: Thank you! So I have to assure that I do not have files with the same name in the folder, right?

Comment: Yes that's right. If a file is found in `/assets/` then it will be served otherwise a redirect will take place to `/folder/assets/...`

Comment: I actually just realised that there seems to be not much else of a possibility. Thank you for your help!